# How do I fix a node server error, npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 1?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, npm

> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
>   npm ERR! errno 1
>   npm ERR! node-express@1.0.0 start: `node server`
>   npm ERR! Exit status 1
>   npm ERR! 
>   npm ERR! Failed at the node-express@1.0.0 start script.
>   npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
>   npm ERR!     /Users/teevee/.npm/_logs/2020-05-30T18_42_30_526Z-debug.log

I haven't had any issues until I had to add routes for partners and promotions in my project.  I don't know how to debug this type of error in order to make the needed changes. What can possibly be the issue? I'm still learning.  Here is a link: https://github.com/TanishaV842/node-express/tree/master/routes

Comment: Did you try to clear npm cache or deleting, `package-lock.json` and `node_modules`?

Comment: Not sure, but it looks like in your `routes/<type>Router.js`, the .route(`/<path>`) code is also duplicated in your main server.js code. Do you need both route definitions? it seems like one or the other would suffice.

Comment: Also, look above your `npm ERR!` log for the stacktrace, that may lead you to the line in your source code that produced the error, and in many cases, tell you why the error was thrown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the issues you have is that it looks like you're including code for your routers in multiple places:

```js
// server.js

app.use("/campsites", campsiteRouter);
app.use("/partners", partnerRouter);
app.use("/promotions", promotionRouter);

campsiteRouter.route("/campsites").all(...);
partnerRouter.route("/partners").all(...);
promotionsRouter.route("/promotions").all(...);
```

There's no need to do that, just do `app.use("/campsites", campsiteRouter);` and get rid of the router code inside `server.js`.

---

Second, the code inside of your `routers` is incorrect in two ways:

```js
// these are two different routes, so create a separate
// route for `/campsites/:campsiteId`,
// additionally, you don't want to do `/campsites/:campsiteId` 
// because you specified the `/campsite` route/portion inside of 
// your `server.js` file when you did 
// `app.use("/campsites", campsiteRouter)`, so only use `/:campsiteId`

// WRONG
campsiteRouter
  .route("/campsites")
  .all(...)
  .get("/campsites/:campsiteId", ...)

// CORRECT
campsiteRouter
  .route("/:campsiteId")
  .all(...)
  .get((req, res) => {
    console.log(req.params.campsiteId);
  })
  .post(...);
```

Here's your fixed code:

- [GitHub](https://github.com/goto1/node-express-fix)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, you are right!  I saw that my code was incorrect inside my routers. So I corrected that and still had errors.  Then I saw your response regarding my code for my routers being in multiple places. The problems are now fixed. Thank you so much! I certainly learned and know not to make that same mistake in the future.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're mixing up regular `router.get()` with `router.route().get()` method parameters.

Because you're using the [`router.route()`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#router.route) method, your:

`.get()`
`.post()`
`.delete()`

call can't pass in a string and a callback. They only except a callback function.

To fix,

change all of the `router.route(...).get('<path>', (req, res) => {})`

to something like:

`router.route(...).get((req, res) => {})`

No path parameter.